# get likes_count, comments, location from Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook, instagram, access-token, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

We are using Instagram Basic Display. Now we can get profile data and allMedia from instagram using this requests:
`https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=account_type%2Cmedia_count%2Cusername&access_token={token}`
`https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=media_type%2Cmedia_url%2Ccaption&access_token={token}`

It's working. I am getting token like here [Instagram Basic Display Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started#step-4--authenticate-the-test-user)
using this request after redirect project url
`https://instoxx-web.vercel.app/api/exchangeCode?code={code}`

BUT, I can't do requests to [https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{any_endpoint}](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/%7Bany_endpoint%7D) using this access_token.
For example when I do simplest request like this
[https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/6251966564860830?fields=id,media_count,username&access_token={token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/6251966564860830?fields=id,media_count,username&access_token=%7Btoken%7D) I see that error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190,
        "fbtrace_id": "A-Htxc8hKArcAl0AR79VyvL"
    }
}
```

I've tried long-lived token as well. It didn't change anything.
Can I send request to Instagram Graph API without using facebook login? How can I get likes, comments adn location from instagram? Is that possible when I am using Instagram Basic Display?
Help me, please. I will be gratefull!

I've tried generate token using this request
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID
&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
It returns acessToken something like `"200241336035340|V7Sgi0wk5AH34sdffWPv2i5IcioGxM"`
And When I use this token I see `"Error validating application. Invalid application ID."` But ID is correct!

Comment: Can you debug the access token using the Access Token Debugger tool? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: If you want to make a call to any `https://graph.facebook.com/....` endpoint, you will need to use the appropriate access token. You will need to implement Login in order to get user and page access tokens. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/
The access token `200241336035340|V7Sgi0wk5AH34sdffWPv2i5IcioGxM` seems to be an app access token and has limited use.

Comment: You can use the `GET /{ig-media-id}` endpoint to get information such as `like_count` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media Other endpoints are listed here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/ You can also use the Graph API explorer tool to test API endpoints https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/